# Nexus 4 disable vibrate

Tags: nexus-4, 5.1-lollipop, vibration

I am using a Google Nexus 4, running Android 5.1.1.

I am trying to disable vibrations when I use the unlock pattern, or the main button panel home, back, and open apps tray.

All of these buttons cause a vibration. I just did a factory reset and this problem arised. Before factory reset they did not vibrate. Factory reset did not change android version.

I have already disabled vibrate in the keyboard options. Where else can I disable it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what needs to be done:

Launch *Settings* app → go to *Sound & notification* → tap *Other sounds* and slide leftwards the switch for *Vibrate on touch* to disable the latter.

<sub>(Click an image to enlarge it)</sub>

[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]